# Delphi: TCoolBar + TToolBar+TEdit+TCheckBox

Tags: delphi, toolbar, edit

How can I put ToolBar on the left side of CoolBar, Edit - center, CheckBox - on the right?

I am trying to do this during 2 hours and I can not:( Controls are behind others, or have a width as CoolBar. Stupid things :)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you really want a nice toolbar, forget Coolbar, and get something else. Anything.   If your app is opensource there's toolbar2000+SpTBX.  If it's closed source, a license for toolbar2000 is quite cheap.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use TCoolBar

Comment: Since you apparently want your toolbar to look like uTorrent's, could you please post a picture of that program so those who are unfamiliar with it can see what you're talking about?

Comment: I would like my Ford Focus to look like a Porsche. :-)

Comment: but how did they make a gradient like in CoolBar?

Comment: Found: http://www.brandonstaggs.com/2009/06/29/give-a-delphi-ttoolbar-a-proper-themed-background/

Comment: What about an Edit, it does not have the same height as buttons?

Comment: or an Edit is not in toolbar...

Comment: @maxfax - Correction, the UI has an alternating design. When run under W7 there's a 'RebarWindow32' hosting the two toolbars. Previously I had run it under W2K, I don't know how it is with OS versions in between but it's not related with themes. In either design, the left toolbar takes up the space remaining from the right-aligned one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for the `Break` property of a CoolBand:

> ***Break property (TCoolBand)** causes the band to start on a new line. If Break is true (the default), the band starts a new line at the left side of the TCoolBar control. If Break is false, the band continues on the same line as its predecessor.*

So the steps to get the layout of your image:

- Put a CoolBar on the form (default top aligned) and give it some extra height,
- Set FixedOrder to True, 
  Add a ToolBar, an Edit and a CheckBox to the CoolBar,
- Open the bands collection editor,
- Set of every CoolBand collection item the Break property to False,
- Drag the width of the independent CoolBands (or set the width property of each),
- Set CoolBar.AutoSize to True.

[image]

Comment: This CoolBar behaves stupidly with FixedSize. Bands have a width like 1200px!!! I can not align bands. I resize bands -> then they get mixed. I hate this coolbar...If it would be a man I would  kill him :)

Comment: I think you are right that this component is _hard to handle_ (and that's mildly). Though you should not get so emotional. Did you get the comment of Sertac Akyuz about uTorrent?

Comment: No? Where can I get? How did they can do it?

Comment: @maxfax It's the latest comment to this question.

Comment: I am sorry, I have looked all and have not seen :)

Answer (score 4):

A screenshot of what your design should look like would help but placing them on seperate `TPanels` gives you more freedom sort to speak.

#### .pas File

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, StdCtrls, ToolWin, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    CoolBar1: TCoolBar;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    tlb1: TToolBar;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    btnToolbar: TToolButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

#### .dfm File

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 348
  ClientWidth = 643
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 348
    Height = 348
    Align = alLeft
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 458
    ExplicitHeight = 185
    object CoolBar1: TCoolBar
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 346
      Height = 75
      Bands = <>
      ExplicitLeft = 96
      ExplicitTop = 136
      ExplicitWidth = 150
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 348
    Top = 0
    Width = 295
    Height = 348
    Align = alClient
    Caption = 'Panel2'
    TabOrder = 1
    ExplicitLeft = 432
    ExplicitTop = 128
    ExplicitWidth = 185
    ExplicitHeight = 41
    object tlb1: TToolBar
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 293
      Height = 29
      Caption = 'tlb1'
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitLeft = 72
      ExplicitTop = 160
      ExplicitWidth = 150
      object btnToolbar: TToolButton
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Caption = 'btnToolbar'
        ImageIndex = 0
      end
    end
    object CheckBox1: TCheckBox
      Left = 80
      Top = 166
      Width = 97
      Height = 17
      Caption = 'CheckBox1'
      TabOrder = 1
    end
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 280
    Top = 164
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
end
```

Comment: Will I have an effect like in uTorrent (please look at it's CoolBar)?

Comment: I need to have all controls on CoolBar

Comment: @maxfax - sorry but that wasn't clear to me in your question. Anyway, your answer seems to have been solved already so there's no point in trying to adjust this answer.